# loadbalancing with apache2

Tags: webserver, client, load-balancing, internal-load-balancer

I have two web servers which host a web page and a load balancer. I installed apache2 and httpd in load balancer but it does not work because when I want to load the web page from a client it cannot find the web page in load balancer.

Comment: Perhaps you could be a bit more informative, are you receiving an error message? Is there anything in the apache error log?

Comment: apache2 works fine. but it could not find the webpage. when I load 192.168.56.101:8080 , apache2 default page is loaded but when i want to load 192.168.56.101:8080/ssd.php "URL was not found on the server".